# How to overcome the PowerShell SSL import delay?

Tags: powershell, ubuntu, certificate

I'm facing an issue when it comes to importing SSL certificates with PowerShell.

The following works:

```
Get-UntrustedRemoteCertificate `
  -CanonicalName my-fqdn.com `
  -Port 443 `
  -OutputPath /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/my-fqdn.com.crt
update-ca-certificates
curl https://my-fqdn.com/
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
...
```

However, if the following is run immediately after `update-ca-certificates`, it'll fail:

```
Invoke-WebRequest https://my-fqdn.com/
Invoke-WebRequest: The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: UntrustedRoot
```

Now, if I wait for 5-6 minutes and reissue the `Invoke-WebRequest`, it'll work just fine.

So obviously there is some sort of delay when it comes to PowerShell handling certificates which is not dependent on the underlying system (drawing from the fact that curl works without a delay).

I would be really happy to understand what is really going on under the hood and possibly figure out how to overcome the issue without writing retry-logic.

Comment: Did you check whenever running a new process changes the behavior? Did you check what you can see using the [Certificate provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/about/about_certificate_provider?view=powershell-7.2) directly after running that update? It might be worth it to check if .NET has any CRL cache or similar on linux.

Comment: I did. and I hate to say that the only way I could overcome this issue was to initiate a new PSSession.